# Fast way to build mobile application with native c++ library

Tags: c++, html, mobile

I'm thinking about building a mobile application. My first target is the iPad/iPhone devices. Android target could be nice to have also. I have already coded and tested the application for win32 and I like to port it to mobile platforms with a minimum effort.

My application is written in C++. its main function is to parse a string presenting a mathematical expression (Script language). I isolated the platform independent code in a static library that I compiled successfully for iOS using Xcode. I need to add some UI to interact with the library. The interaction is done in the two directions. The UI send string expressions for evaluation to the static library and call some function to read the variables values (mainly vectors (tables) of float and strings). On the other side, the library needs some external function for printing text results on a TextView and some plotting functions.

In my UI layer I need to call some external "C" functions exported by the static library like :

```
int ExecuteExpression(char *expression)
void StopExecution()
```

Inside my library I need to call some external "C" functions exported by UI application , like :

```
void PrintText(char *text)
void Plot2D(double *x, double *y, int len);
void plot3D(double *x, double *y, double *z, int len);
```

I looked to [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/) IDE, but it does not allow calling user made static libraries.

I looked also to [Marmalade EDK](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmalade/features/extensions-development-kit-edk) and it seems a good way to make a UI that call a user defined static library by writing extensions. I don't understand why i must write an EDK to wrap my library functions for marmalade because the final project is compiled inside Xcode and I think that I must be able to call directly my "C" function and link with my library. But Does Marmalde give the native look & feel of iOS UI? can i draw directly on the NSView using C++ using the marmalade API?

For the plotting functions I have several choices :
1- Make drawing in buffer image of (RGB) inside my library and send the image data to the UI to display inside a View (NSView). Interaction with plots will be very limited in this case.  Redrawing when changing the View dimensions will be an issue to be solved because the plotting routine must remember all actions made for drawing a graph.

2- Use HTML5/JS function to draw in the UI layer. in this case I must be able to export HTML5/JS function as "C" function like "Plot2D(double *x, double *y, int len)" to call them from the library. A copy of data will be saved by the UI layer and redrawing , zooming, etc will be managed by the HTML5/JS code. Is this possible ? Is there any example for calling HTML5/JS from "C" static library ?

3- Export primitive drawing functions (like Line, point, rectangle, polygonfill, canvashandle,etc..) from the UI layer to my static lib and make the library manage all the plotting functions. The UI will send some events also for redrawing, zooming, etc.

4- Any other solution you propose.

As you can understand from my post, I Master C, C++, JS, HTML5, delphi and have only some basic knowledge about Objective-C and the iOS UIkit. So I'm trying to find the most efficient way to make my application.

Regards,

Comment: "I Master C, C++, JS, HTML5" you are either a genius or a tad too optimistic. I've been working in C++ for 5 years now, I've explored the language a lot, and I still consider myself a freshman ;)

Comment: so I'm a genius :). No, I mean that I master enough to feel that i'm able to write any application I can imagine in C++/JS/HTML5 in a short time (I already made complex C++ applications in 3 or 5 months when the estimated time for other experienced developers was 2 man.yrs. The secret : I have a code piece for nearly every task. I spend time to optimize code "reuse" rather than writing code myself). I have 20 years experience "using" C++. I'm used to write non buggy code even it's not very clean all the time.

Comment: I looked to Marmalade SDK in more details. It's very good for direct drawing on a canvas. But the examples i saw for the UI don't have the look & feel of iOS at all. I looked to the lwNUI samples and i was disappointed. Marmalade could be the right direction if I found a way to make native UI (buttons, lists, Text, etc...). Any experience with HTML5 for the UI and marmalade for drawing in C++ on the canvas?